# Sort characters by frequency

Tags: python, algorithm

Input:
"tree"

Output:
"eert"

Explanation:
'e' appears twice while 'r' and 't' both appear once.
So 'e' must appear before both 'r' and 't'. Therefore "eetr" is also a valid answer.

I tried something like this :

```
class Solution(object):
def frequencySort(self, s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    has = dict()
    l = list()
    for c in s:
        if c not in has:
            has[c] = 1
        else:
            has[c] += 1
    for k in sorted(has,key = has.get, reverse = True):
        for i in range(has[k]):
            l.extend(k)
    return ("".join(l))
```

but its O(n * m) 
n = length of string, m = maximum occurrence of a character

How can i improve this to order of n?

Comment: maybe `return ''.join(c * t for c, t in collections.Counter(s).most_common())` http://bookshadow.com/weblog/2016/11/02/leetcode-sort-characters-by-frequency/

Comment: `sorted(s, key=Counter(s).get, reverse=True)` works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use the built in sort with a lambda key?

```
>>> a = 'aabbbcccccd'
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda c: a.count(c))
['d', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda c: a.count(c), reverse=True)
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd']
>>> ''.join(sorted(a, key=lambda c: a.count(c), reverse=True))
'cccccbbbaad'
```

I believe python's sort methods is `O(n log n)`, but the `count` will make this `O(n^2)`

Comment: I think this is **O(n^2)**, since `count` has to traverse the entire list for each character.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier You are forgetting the `a.count(c)` calls there.

Comment: You are correct @Prune. Is there a way this can be faster?